# How can I create and Apache Axiom element from a E4X object from a script running in Rhino?

Tags: soap, apache-axis, rhino, e4x, axiom

I am running a script running in Rhino, which creates an E4X object like this:

```
var s =     <product id="123">
                    <name>Google Search</name>
                    <source>https://google.com</source>
            </product>
```

I want to include such XML in a SOAP message. I am using [Apache Axis 2 ServiceClient](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_1/api/org/apache/axis2/client/ServiceClient.htm) for creating soap message. What I am looking for is a way to convert the E4X xml object into an Apache AXIOM element so that it can be added to SOAP message via a call to:

[ServiceClient.addHeader(org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement omElement)](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_1/api/org/apache/axis2/client/ServiceClient.html#addHeader(org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far it appears that converting E4X object to String and then using StAXOMBuilder (or one of it's subclasses) is the simplest option.

```
  XMLInputFactory xif= XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
  XMLStreamReader reader= xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(stringFromRhinoE4X));
  StAXOMBuilder builder=new StAXOMBuilder(reader);
  OMElement header= builder.getDocumentElement();
```

**Edit**: Although the above code works, the resulting OMElement cannot be passed to ServiceClient.addHeader(org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement omElement). Following code can be used to create an OMElement representing SOAPHeader:

```
CharArrayDataSource arrayDataSource = new CharArrayDataSource(contentXML.toCharArray());
SOAPFactory factory =  OMAbstractFactory.getSOAP12Factory();
SOAPHeaderBlock soapHeader = factory.createSOAPHeaderBlock(headerName, factory.createOMNamespace(namespace, nameSpacePrefix), arrayDataSource);
service.addHeader(soapHeader);
```